# File being written when it is being moved by another application

Tags: java, file

Hi i have two applications. One that creates files and write some data in to it. Another that copies the files to another location at scheduled intervals. If the files are being written at the time my second app is moving it some data is being lost. Is their any way by which my files are moved only when they are completely written?

Comment: what do you want from us???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `concurrency control mechanism`. Java 5 comes with read / write lock implementations in the `java.util.concurrent` package. You can refer [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your writer should write to a temporary file in a different folder first and then move the file when it has been completely written. On most filesystems moves are atomic (obviously the move must not be across two different disks).